# What is the BunsenLabs version of Ubuntu?

Tags: distro-recommendation

I love Debian, but I dislike desktop managers. Trying to set up Openbox by myself was confusing, so I was thrilled when I discovered BunsenLabs.
However, a lot of applications that call themselves "Linux compatible" (Steam, GOG games...) really are Ubuntu compatible, which makes a huge difference.

Since I have a growing list of problems with those, I think it would be better to get an Ubuntu flavor.

So, is there an Ubuntu flavor or derivative which scraps the desktop manager, has Openbox (or another window manager) already configured, and scraps the Amazon integration by default? A BunsenLabs Ubuntu edition in short?

Comment: Lubuntu is probably closest to what you want - http://lubuntu.net/

Comment: I've understood (but haven't confirmed) that Lubuntu uses the same lightdm that Xubuntu does.

Comment: @terdon: While steam does run in debian, it is not without going throught a few hoops, but I agree I may not have chosen the best example with it. Getting support however, become very difficult as Valve (or GOG) will simply answer you to use the right distribution, and not investigate even if the app is unusable.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: It also seems xfce was a default alternative for Openbox back in #! (BunsenLabs ancestor), and BunsenLabs itself use component of xfce. I will try it out and see if it fit my needs :)

Comment: Also, I d like to point out that a reason I avoided Ubuntu for so long is also because of the integration with Amazon, a note on that in your reccomendation is welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, every variant flavor of Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu) has a desktop manager (KDM, lightdm, etc.), rather than Openbox or another direct window manager.

That said, I don't know of any reason Openbox couldn't be installed in Ubuntu, given that Bunsenlabs is Debian based and so is Ubuntu.  However: you're likely to find that software that's "Ubuntu compatible" depends on finding a desktop manager, and won't know what to do with Openbox anyway.  In other words, if you manage to get Ubuntu running with Openbox, you may find you've removed most of the things that applications depend on to be compatible.

I'm not at all sure what you mean by "Amazon integration" -- I've been running Kubuntu for almost three years, and the only time I see anything related to Amazon is when I shop from my browser.  I don't use a personal cloud (I do have a Dropbox, but use it only for limited, specific storage that I need to access from multiple devices), but I'm sure there are choices even for that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the fact apps would need a desktop manager when a window manager is available? Reinstalling component of a desktop manager when needed is fine (BunsenLabs have some of xfce component, notably the power manager). However, I find full blown desktop manager too heavy and invasive.

Comment: I doubt the presence of the desktop manager will be needed. AFAIK, the programs mentioned by the OP run through wine anyway, so I doubt they'd need anything from the DM.

Comment: OP specifically mentions "Linux compatible" programs that really mean "Ubuntu compatible".  I don't know GoG, but Steam has a Linux native client (which, as I recall, really is for Ubuntu specifically).

Comment: @ZeissIkon: Well, if you are willing to jump throught some hoops, you can make the Steam client work in Debian, but if a game doesn't work, or you need help, you are on your own. But if you have any ubuntu  derivative, you can ask for help, or a refund because the game doesn't work. Same for Gog, technically, nothing prevent it from working, but at the slighest bump, you are out in the cold.

Comment: @ZeissIkon no it's not. I've installed Steam (without any hoops, it's in the repos) on both Debian and Arch.